# How to retrieve data from an API and load to Azure SQL database in Azure Functions in Python?

Tags: api, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, cloud

I'm really just looking for a short Python example using Azure functions that pulls in some data from an API (any) pushes it to an Azure SQL database based on a timer trigger.

Any resources or examples would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Spend 5 minutes on this and ask a more specific question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple python Azure function demo code for you,I created a table named `demotable` with only 2 colms : `id`(primary key,auto increment) and `content`(varchar,used for saving API response).

This is my code :

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import requests
import pyodbc

SQLConnStr = '<your sql conntion string>'

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    result = requests.get("https://google.com")    
    print(result.status_code)

    conn = pyodbc.connect(SQLConnStr)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("insert into demotable values ('"+str(result.status_code)+"')")
    cursor.commit()
    conn.close()
```

requirement.txt:

```
azure-functions
requests
pyodbc
```

Each time this function will access google and save the response status code into SQL.

Result:

[image]

For how to use VS code to develop an Azure python function, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python).

And make sure that you have enabled the Azure SQL firewall for your Azure function before you access it. Details [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup).

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Awesome thanks for that! So basically an azure sql database can be used the same way any normal SQL database can as long as you have the right firewall settings and a connection string?

Comment: @Tujamo, welcome, that's right, you can use it the same way as a common DB